# How do I import an Android Studio project from Git?

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android Studio project which I've added to a Git repository on Bitbucket. I'm now trying to import the same project into Android Studio on a different computer.  Problem is, it doesn't seem to be importing as a project, just as some files, if that makes sense.

I start by opening Android Studio and going to "VCS > Checkout from Version Control > Git". Then I get the "Clone Repository" window, where I add the Bitbucket server (I hit 'Test' and it's fine), Parent Directory and Directory Name. Then I hit "Clone".

Then I get a window saying "Would you like to create a Studio project for the sources you have checked out to [directory]?".

If I hit "No", nothing else seems to happen.

If I hit "Yes", I get the "Import Project" window. I can select one of the following:

1. Create project from  existing sources. Hit 'Next', set Project Name & Location, hit Next, select source files (there's one checkbox, so I check it), hit Next again, and it says "No frameworks detected".
2. Import project from external model. Select 'Gradle', hit 'Next', select "Use local gradle distribution", hit 'Next', and it says "Unable to load class org.slf4j.loggerfactory".

I've no idea what I'm doing, so I stopped at that point!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try from linux command-line :

```
git clone https://github.com/......git
```

then try to add a new project 'from existing sources'

NOTE: on windows machine you can install git-bash and do the procedure above